# How to delete old items from a list that is periodically changing from a website?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, beautifulsoup

So I have this code that prints all of the products on adidas US and I want it to scrape for when new products are added to the list, then print that one new product. Right now it can only print out the entire list of products. How would I do this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import urllib.parse
import time

headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8"}

url = 'http://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-US-Library/en_US/v/sitemap/product/adidas-US-en-us-product.xml'

values = {'s':'search',
'submit':'search'}


data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers=headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

rawdata = re.findall(r'<loc>(.*?)</loc>', str(respData))

for Product_list in rawdata:
    print(Product_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to recollect data periodically, just check to see if there are new product URLs at time B, compared to those observed at time A.  Here's a short example.

Note: I replaced `urllib` with `requests`.  Also, you imported `BeautifulSoup` but didn't use it - I've used it here instead of `re`.  Neither one of these replacements is strictly necessary, they're just my personal preferences.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.8"}
url = 'http://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-US-Library/en_US/v/sitemap/product/adidas-US-en-us-product.xml'
values = {'s':'search', 'submit':'search'}

# replace urllib with requests
r = requests.post(url, values, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

# replace re with soup
products = [str(p.text) for p in soup.find_all('loc')]

# sample output
print(products[0:5])
['http://www.adidas.com/us/ultraboost-shoes/BA8842.html',
 'http://www.adidas.com/us/ultraboost-shoes/BA8843.html',
 'http://www.adidas.com/us/crazypower-trainer-shoes/BA8929.html',
 'http://www.adidas.com/us/alphabounce-aramis-shoes/B54366.html',
 'http://www.adidas.com/us/harden-vol.-1-shoes/B39494.html']
```

Now let's say you pull data again using the same process and you get the following response.  The first link is copied from `products`, and the second link is new:

```
new_products = ['http://www.adidas.com/us/ultraboost-shoes/BA8842.html',
                'http://www.adidas.com/us/ultraboost-shoes/foo.html']
```

There are a number of ways to check for the existence of elements from one list in another list.  I like the `isin()` method offered by Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
new_products = pd.Series(new_products)

# get only new products not in old products
mask = ~new_products.isin(products)
new_products[mask].values
['http://www.adidas.com/us/ultraboost-shoes/foo.html']
```